# How do I intercept and modify the functionality of wp_get_attachment_image()?

Tags: attachments, images

I have a site I'm building in wordpress that has ~80GB of high resolution images, and it's exceeding my managed host's storage space. My plan is to move all the images to S3, but I noticed that `wp_get_attachment_image()` automatically prefixes the src with `/wp-content/uploads` instead of respecting the path stored in the database.

Is there a way to hook into that method and modify it to not include the prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a solution to string replace /wp-content/uploads with '' (empty) like for an example:

Lets say: wp_get_attachment_image() returns = '/wp-content/uploads/myimage.png';

```
<?php
echo str_replace('/wp-content/uploads/', '', wp_get_attachment_image()); 
?>
```

This will result in echo: 'myimage.png'

Try this:

```
function alter_image_src($attr) {
  $attr['src'] = str_replace('/wp-content/uploads/', '', $attr['src']);
  return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'alter_image_src');
```

In your functions page (of theme).

Comment: I would do this, but there are dozens and dozens of places where that method is being called in the admin theme we've picked.

Comment: Could you try the updated answer?

Comment: You figured it out before I could reply :D, well done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can intercept and str_replace in an intercept on `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes()`, which is used by the higher level `wp_get_attachment_image()` function.